# How to replace span or class after textbox value change?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

On my .cshtml page I have:

```
<span id="oldDate" class="element-value2">
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Old)
   @Html.ValidationTooltipFor(m => m.Old)
</span>

<span id="actualDate" class="element-value2">
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Actual)
   @Html.ValidationTooltipFor(m => m.Actual)
</span>
```

element-value2 make them to be datepicker with callendar button.
By default, m.Actual value is null (nullable DateTime).

What I need to do is, if m.Actual value has changed to something, I need to replace oldDate span with
new one:

```
<span>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Old, new { disabled = "disabled", @class = "special-container fixed" })</span>
```

and return it back, if m.Actual value were removed.

How can this may be done?

P.S Sorry about my bad English.

Comment: I suppose you can make hidden field for `m.Old` and do your manipulations via `javascript`.

Comment: Your container should be a `<div>` not a `<span>`. What the point of setting `disabled = "disabled"`? That just **prevents** the value from posting back. You can easily do a check on the server `if(model.Actual.HasValue) { \\ ignore model.Old }`

Comment: Yes, its prevents values from posting back, all just planned.

Comment: I thinked already about div show and hide but... how it should look?

Comment: $('#Actual').change(function() { $('#oldDate').hide(); });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do this. 
Try like following. This may help you

```
$('#Actual').change(function () {
        var actual = $(this).val();
        var old = $('#Old');
        if (actual == '') {
            old.parent().attr('class', 'element-value2');
            old.removeAttr('class');
            old.removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            old.parent().removeAttr('class');
            old.attr('class', 'special-container fixed');
            old.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Em... there are not used span Id but part model instead? (m.Actual)

Comment: it is using the rendered html from cshtml file.

Comment: Made a few changes but yep, the idea behind this sample helped a lot.